# How to override mail.model js class function in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

in file "addons/mail/static/src/models/message_action_list/message_action_list.js"
there is a js class:

```
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registerNewModel } from '@mail/model/model_core';
import { attr, many2one, one2one } from '@mail/model/model_field';
import { clear, insertAndReplace, replace } from '@mail/model/model_field_command';
import { markEventHandled } from '@mail/utils/utils';

function factory(dependencies) {

    class MessageActionList extends dependencies['mail.model'] {

        /**
         * @private
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        _computeHasReplyIcon() {
            ...
        }

        ...

    }

    MessageActionList.fields = {
        ...
    };
    MessageActionList.identifyingFields = ['messageView'];
    MessageActionList.modelName = 'mail.message_action_list';

    return MessageActionList;
}

registerNewModel('mail.message_action_list', factory);
```

I want to override a `_computeHasReplyIcon()` function.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `registerInstancePatchModel` to override the `_computeHasReplyIcon` function as  they did in the [im_livechat](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/im_livechat/static/src/models/message_action_list/message_action_list.js) module:

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registerInstancePatchModel } from '@mail/model/model_core';

registerInstancePatchModel('mail.message_action_list', 'im_livechat/static/src/models/message_action_list/message_action_list.js', {

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * @override
     */
    _computeHasReplyIcon() {
        if (
            this.message &&
            this.message.originThread &&
            this.message.originThread.channel_type === 'livechat'
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        return this._super();
    }
});
```